# css animation with spritesheet

Tags: css, css-animations

trying to follow the blog post [treehouse tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/learn-asynchronous-image-loading-javascript) and coded everything pretty much like the tutorial said but my animation wont start or work. My little image shows up fine and its a 490 x 110 sprite sheet. The code im using is the following:

```
.ken {
  width: 70px;
  height: 110px;
  background: url('/imgs/ken-shoryuken.png') left center;
  animation: play 1.5s steps(7) infinite;
}
@keyframes play {
   100% { background-position:-490; }
}
```

And it is positioned by a simple dive which is showing up fine, its just the animation wont work for some reason, any thoughts?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or plunkr demonstrating it? Your animation only has 1 step and that might be it. Usually you have to do @keyframes play{ 0%{}, 100%{}}.

Comment: I would but the asset file is stored locally can i upload it in fiddle

Comment: What property are you trying to animate? or what are you trying to have the sprite do?

Comment: You need to specify a length, you probably want `px` -- `background-position:-490px;` -- [Like this example](http://jsbin.com/guwiru/1/edit)

Comment: Oh right, and also animations still need vendor tags, like -webkit-animation, @-webkit-keyframes

Comment: awesome i was missing the simple 'px' suffix lol, alsways the little things. make an answer misterman and ill check mark it

Comment: @KevinF - We can celebrate, the end of prefixes is nigh - [Stable Chrome no longer requires CSS animation prefixes](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)!

Comment: oh that's cool! I always forget to add prefixes until after about 20 minutes of debugging

Comment: @misterManSam still have a ways to go though, probably w/in the year or two

Comment: someone write an answer so i can accept it and get the points

Answer (score 0):

You need to [specify an absolute length unit, keyword or percentage for `background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position):

```
@keyframes play {
   100% { background-position:-490px; }
}
```

> [Background position] Syntax
>
> - background-position: top;
> - background-position: bottom;
> - background-position: left;
> - background-position: right;
> - background-position: center;
> - background-position: 25% 75%;
> - background-position: 0px 0px, center;